# Users get redirected to different server name URL when searching in a FBA WSS v3 site

Tags: 2007, search

I have configured a FBA site and the search does work which means crawling is OK.
But when FBA users enter a search word and hit ok they get a different servername.
The site was extended from a Windows Auth to a Forms Auth.

This is what i have in my AAM settings
the Windows Auth site was http://servername:8080 internal URL and Zone is Default
then extended to forms auth using to http://extranet:7070  Zone is Extranet
and http://extranet.servername.com Zone is Internet.

How can i change the URL to change from http://extranet:7070  to http://extranet.servername.com when users get
redirected after doing a search.
When users do a search they get to
http://extranet:7070/sites/mysite/_layouts/searchresults.aspx?k=Direct
But when i manually amend the URL to what i want below i still get the search result
http://extranet.servername.com/sites/mysite/_layouts/searchresults.aspx?k=Direct

How to get the search button to redirect to the second URL..

Any ideas?

Comment: @Patrick: Please make an effort to use this system properly. Most of all this helps *you* get good answers. If your post isn't gaining attention, **edit it with more details** on what you have tried. If you are responding to someone that has left you an answer, **please use the comment feature**. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, say i'm a user browsing to http://extranet:7070. I type in a search term in the search box at the top of the page. I click on a result. What does my URL look like? Does it begin with http://extranet:7070 or http://servername:8080? Do you want to show this as http://extranet.mycompany.com?